# Nginx - How to get the count of requests handled by each upstream IP in the upstream block?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, openresty, nginx-upstreams

```
upstream test {
    server ip1:port1;
    server ip1:port2;
    server ip1:port3;
    server ip1:port4;
}
location / {
    set $dst  test;
    proxy_pass http://$dst;
}
```

Approach -
Initially in the database, I stored the request count of each upstream IP in the upstream block with zero.
When a request is made to Nginx, I get the upstream IP used by proxy_pass, Then perform an ngx.location.capture subrequest to the database to increment the count of an upstream IP.

But How can I perform ngx.location.capture after proxy_pass?

Is there any other approach to achieve this?

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that **after proxy_pass** means that you don't want your DB to slow down the response to the client.

In the [official reference under Directives](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/) you can see that the "Log Phase" is the last phase that is entered after the content phase that sends data. As the [reference also tells](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/#log_by_lua), the code executed in the log phase has no chance to alter the content (because it's sent already).

The second limit is that there is no `ngx.location.capture` available. So your DB basically has to be updated by the lua code, not by running a subrequest.

Basic idea using [LuaSQLite3](http://lua.sqlite.org):

```
upstream test {
    server ip1:port1;
    server ip1:port2;
    server ip1:port3;
    server ip1:port4;
}
location / {
    set $dst  test;
    proxy_pass http://$dst;

    log_by_lua_block {
        local sqlite3 = require("lsqlite3")
        local db = sqlite3.open('access_list.sqlite3')
        db:exec([[
          CREATE TABLE logs (
            backend     VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            access      INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
          );
        ]])

        local prep = db:prepare('INSERT INTO logs(backend) VALUES (:backend) ON CONFLICT(backend) DO UPDATE SET access=access+1')
        prep:bind_names({ backend = ngx.var.dst })
        prep:step()
        prep:reset()
        db:close()
    }
}
```

You can further optimize here if you start the db connection in the init phase of openresty.